# Adding Popup control using Xaml shifts other control on page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

When I add Popup to my XAML like this

```
<Grid>
   ...other controls
   <Popup x:Name="popup" Width="200" Height="200" >

   </Popup>
</Grid>
```

It behaves as though the popup is there even though I did not toggle IsOpen = true (but the space is blank so no popup is visible)

However when I do the same from the code behind (add a popup) like this, it works like it should, it doesn't interfere with any controls (i.e. shift them) and it pops up as expected over top the other controls.

```
        Popup p = new Popup();

            // Create some content to show in the popup. Typically you would 
        // create a user control.
        Border border = new Border();
        border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);

        StackPanel panel1 = new StackPanel();
        panel1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.);

        Button button1 = new Button();
        button1.Content = "Close";
        button1.Margin = new Thickness(5.0);
        button1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Feedback_Click);
        TextBlock textblock1 = new TextBlock();
        textblock1.Text = "The popup control";
        textblock1.Margin = new Thickness(5.0);
        panel1.Children.Add(textblock1);
        panel1.Children.Add(button1);
        border.Child = panel1;

        // Set the Child property of Popup to the border 
        // which contains a stackpanel, textblock and button.
        p.Child = border;

        // Set where the popup will show up on the screen.
        p.VerticalOffset = 400;
        p.HorizontalOffset = 150;

        // Open the popup.
        p.IsOpen = true;
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish the same thing in the XAML?

Comment: When I try this on my computer it behaves correctly in runtime. In designtime it occupies the space. Is this the behavior you are experiencing as well? It seems that you are using a `Grid` in XAML and `StackPanel` in code behind. Just as a reminder, these containers behave very differently.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of using a `Popup`. It can be an overlay control **or** it can be defined in the layout (or added to the tree) and it will take space like a standard control.

To have an overlay popup but avoid defining the layout in code-behind and still u, two techniques are often used:

1) defining the popup content as a separate user control. Your event handlers like `Feedback_Click` would now be definded in code-behind of the `UserControl`

```
var p = new Popup { Child = new MyControl() };
p.IsOpen = true;
```

2) defining the popup content simply in xaml in `ResourceDictionary`.

Comment: I tried making a user control, but again when it comes time to using it in my page, it takes up space.  I want it to be invisible until it's time to open it and overlay over everything else.  Do I initialize the user control in codebehind and open close it from code?

Comment: @erotavlas Yes, as shown in the code sample. The UserControl stuff is just so that you didn't have to declare the *layout* of the Popup in code behind, but the Popup should be created in code behind.